# How to append number sign (#) to the URL in php

Tags: php

I have this row in a php file. It creates the URL path:

```
$output = l($image, "article/{$article->aid}", $options);
```

The output is good, but I want to append '#' sign with a word to it. E. g.:

```
/articles/example#comments
```

I have tried with different combinations, but didn't find the right one. I hoped that the plus sign combination will work, but then it always points to the root:

```
$output = l($image, "article/{$article->aid}"+"#comments", $options);

Result is "/"
```

Does someone know how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Concatenation in PHP is done with the dot operator.  `"article/{$article->aid}" . "#comments"` Or just `"article/{$article->aid}#comments"` in a double-quoted string.

Comment: Seriously, you could not find out how to concatenate strings in PHP by googling or looking at PHP docs?

Comment: @MikeBrant You really think that someone who is a newbie knows what concatenation is? I googled for appending different stuff and didn't find anything about concatenation.

Comment: @Tommy Yet they know enough to know that strings can be put together and they randomly guessed the `+` (used in many languages for this purpose) was used to do this?

Comment: @MikeBrant As you can see, I wrote that I googled for it. And found examples with plus sign, which obviously isn't the same. Why on earth would I rather ask here and lose time waiting rather than find it in an article?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concat a string with "+" so instead of

```
$output = l($image, "article/{$article->aid}"+"#comments", $options);
```

it would be

```
$output = l($image, "article/{$article->aid}"."#comments", $options);
```

Comment: Or simply `"article/{$article->aid}#comments"`